# How to Iterate over TensorSliceDataset object in Tensorflow

Tags: python, loops, tensorflow, tensor

I have tensorflow `Dataset` object created by using CIFAR-100 dataset.I need to access train labels `TensorSpec` inside the `Dataset` object.Its not possible to access by index since `TensorSliceDataset` object is not support for index.How to access each `TensorSpec` and iterate over values inside that.

```
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = cifar100.load_data(label_mode='fine')
with open('data/cifar100/cifar100_labels.json', 'r') as j:
    cifar_labels = json.load(j)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data,train_labels))
print(train_dataset.element_spec)

# (TensorSpec(shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.uint8, name=None), 
# TensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the labels into an array:

```
import tensorflow as tf

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data,train_labels))

next(dataset.batch(60_000).as_numpy_iterator())[1]
```

```
array([5, 0, 4, ..., 5, 6, 8], dtype=uint8)
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: thank you for your answer.I need to apply filter function for the Dataset object and apply a mask for both labels and data.mask is generate by using labels.I could do is before create the Dataset object using np arrays. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter